# android : best way to open a file in temprory memory

Tags: android

I have a encrypted file, which on decryption is to opened in temporary memory, and when user closes the file they temporary file is deleted, What's the way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: decrypt it into a string kept in memory!?

Comment: no, to open the file itself in temporary storage for reading(It may be any kind of files swf, pdf etc. ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use external storage for the file since it will be available to whole world(what if user ejects SD card before you delete it?)

You should use [***internal storage***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) so that you can remove it once the user is done.  Use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` so that user/other apps can only read it. When user is done, you can delete it.

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();


File file = new File(FILENAME);
file.delete();
```

Comment: But there must be some limit on the maximum internal storage memory for each application.any idea on how much is that?

Comment: It's true but if the file is encrypted I would assume it's sensitive data. If the file is too big maybe you should warn the user and ask if it is ok to use external storage.

Comment: ok.. thanks a lot for replies! Is there any size limit for internal storage.. any ideas?

Comment: I think it depends on the phone model & how much space is used by other apps. Here it says: "you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space", but I would say nowadays you can make it 10MB.

Comment: The url: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29

Answer (score 1):

**Good practice**

Use internal storage and check out this: [getCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29)

---

**Bad practice**

1. ***create the file on your sdcard***

   ```
   extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "filename.ext");   
   try {
       outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       //write data;
       outStream.flush();
       outStream.close();
   }
   ```
2. ***delete the file***

   ```
   extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "filename.ext");  
   boolean deleted = file.delete();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As LAS_VEGAS said using external storage is a terrible idea!!

See this link for cache getCacheDir()

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#InternalCache

or use the normal internal storage with `MODE_PRIVATE`

ie

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

then after wards

```
deleteFile(FILENAME);
```

EDIT: `MODE_PRIVATE` would make it not accessible by other applications so maybe not a good idea !:(

But also if it has to decrypt a file and save it unencrypted, if someone really wanted at that file they could get it I'm sure since you're having it world readable for a while

Comment: `MODE_PRIVATE` would not work because then user cant access the file. He says, file might be of .pdf, .swf etc. So user needs to be able to open it with some other application.

Comment: Hmm, true. But then does internal and external make a difference if he will be deleting them afterwards? And then what's the point of having it encrypted :(

Comment: @dten : but there can be issue in this case, when user has decrypted the data and at the same time removes the SD card, then he can have a decrypted copy of that data..

Comment: yes but if the file is world_readable on internal, the user might have an app that is listening for file changes and makes a copy of that file also. I think the whole idea is flawed to be honest

Comment: @dten- from the [manuals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal):files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).

Comment: You missed the "By default", but if you set mode_world_readable then they ARE accessible to other applications

Comment: @dten If the user can open the file, there will always be a way to copy the content somehow, no way to avoid this(But that is not important because user has already access to the content, at least to view it. Actually in many cases the possibility to copy the content may be desired) The important thing is to prevent unauthorized people getting the data. The decrypted file on sd card is vulnerable to theft. To get the data from internal storage one needs to be able to access to phone, and assuming phone is protected by lock code, the data is protected.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS I agree except if they have a malicious app on there